# Insert record in a table with trigger without shot the trigger

Tags: c#, sql-server, triggers

I'm doing an c# that update a record in a SQL Server 2012. The problem is:

The table of record has a trigger that update one field that I don't want to update (in this case, because I will put it manually).

The trigger is like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TriggerName]
ON [dbo].[TableName]
AFTER UPDATE
```

So, after my update, the trigger jump and rewrite my update.

Is there any way to avoid the trigger?

I know that I could change "AFTER UPDATE" for "INSTEAD UPDATE" but I would prefer if there is any way without touching the trigger (I will do if is the only chance)

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options.

**1. Disable trigger for specific SQL statement:**

Follow the link below. I have never implemented this approach myself so don't have much to say on it.
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1591/disabling-a-trigger-for-a-specific-sql-statement-or-session/

**2. Add a column/attribute:** Add a column to your table called `run_trigger` or something along those lines. Update the trigger to not run when a value is being set in the new column.

This can be dangerous if you retrieve data using `SELECT *` in other queries and stored procedures. Ideally you should never use `SELECT *` in a program or stored procedure.

**3. Update field after trigger:** 
Update the trigger to only be executed when specific columns are updated (i.e. do not run the trigger when the column you want to set is updated). Run the first query, and then manually update/reset the value.

This isn't ideal as you hit the table 2x  more and may cause any audit log to look a little funny.

This solution may not be viable depending on if the trigger should be run in normal scenarios when only the one column is updated.

**4. Disable/Enable trigger:**
You can disable and then re-enable the trigger.

```
ALTER TABLE <table> DISABLE TRIGGER <trigger>;
ALTER TABLE <table> ENABLE TRIGGER <trigger>;
```

This can be dangerous if you do not have/maintain a lock on the table until the trigger is re-enabled. Disabling the trigger opens the door for data corruption. Do not use this approach unless you can have the table locked until after you re-enable the trigger.